# Select value for input[type='file']

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I found a useful snippet on jsFiddle for drag'n'drop images to browser. http://jsfiddle.net/JtJ5N/359/

Now I want to select the dropped image for my form in this page. I have below form:

```
<form id="form1" method='post' action='upload.php' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
    <input id="fileBox" type='file' name='upload'>
    <input type='submit' value='Upload'>                                                                              
</form>
```

I want when image dropped to the page, by clicking submit button, the form submits.

Comment: And what is the problem? Console errors? What?

Comment: Not certain what question is?

Comment: `$('#fileBox').val;`

Comment: @mplungjan I just asked how can I handle this.

Comment: when I select image by clicking search button, everything is fine but the problem is when I drag and drop image, it's not working then.

Comment: @ata Simply drop the file from file manager GUI at `<input id="fileBox" type='file' name='upload'>` element

Answer (score 0):

Files and folders can be dropped at `<input type="file">` elements. No additional code is necessary. Simply drop the selected file from the system file manager GUI at `<input id="fileBox" type='file' name='upload'>` element and click `<input type='submit' value='Upload'>` element.  The file will be submitted to `'upload.php'` as part of the `'multipart/form-data'` encoded `<form>`.

Comment: Currently I'm doing this and no success so I came here to ask.

Comment: @ata What do you mean by "no success"?

Comment: @ata The code at Answer meets requirement at Question. It is not clear what you are expecting as result

Comment: when I hover image into the box, the image is showing in browser but when I press the submit button, nothing is going to server. This is not the case when I select the file as normal (not drag and drop). I want when drop a file in the input, by pressing submit button it goes to server. tnx.

Comment: There should be no difference between selecting a file at `Choose File` dialog and dropping a file at `<input type="file">` element. Do you actually drop the file at `<input type="file">` element?